# How to show permalink auto when type text in post tiltle?

Tags: permalinks

My website when type text in post title, it's not auto show the permalink. It only show when me publish this post.How to do it ?

Thanks everyone
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto Screen Options at the top right of your screen.
Tick the checkbox for Slug.
Type in the post title, then click in the textarea below and the permalink should appear a few seconds later.

Comment: Checked, but not working. Do you have another way ???